# How to create WSP Package of a SharePoint 2010 site without VS 2010 (with SP Designer)?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, solution-package

I am having a site with publishing feature enabled. So "Save site as a template" feature is not available for me. Since I don't have control over the SP server farm, I am not sure about how I can create a WSP package for my SharePoint 2010 site. Is it possible to do with SP Designer 2010?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible to export a site as solution file using SharePoint designer.

Here's the tutorial you are looking for that explains step by step guide for exporting site as a Solution file using SharePoint designer,

http://weblogs.asp.net/soever/archive/2009/10/19/sharepoint-2010-site-exporting-as-wsp-solution-part-1.aspx

Comment: Thank you for your help. Exporting site as a template and importing it to visual studio will
generate complete site deployment package.Here I wanted to go for selective pages and lists only. Is there any way we can do? Thanks,