# How to create a WSP package for a SharePoint 2010 site?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, solution-package, solution-deployment, wspbuilder

I previously asked this Question: [How to create WSP Package of a SharePoint 2010 site without VS 2010 (with SP Designer)?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61433/how-to-create-wsp-package-of-a-sharepoint-2010-site-without-vs-2010-with-sp-des).

But didn't get a proper answer. I am developing a SharePoint 2010 website. I am not the admin for central administration. I am just one Site's administrator in the farm. I just changed the CSS of master pages and added some sub sites, blogs. How can I create a WSP solution with Visual Studio 2012 or SP Designer 2010?

I want to have all the web parts, all the custom master pages, all the modified css, all the libraries and sub-sites that I created. How can I accomplish it?